# Cannot connect Barman to PostgreSQL 12

Tags: postgresql, connection, virtual-machine, vmware, barman

I have 2 ubuntu-20.04 VM on VMWARE with Postgres 12 installed on each
pgprimary on ip 192.168.1.131
pgbackup  on ip 192.168.1.130

barman CLI tools are installed on pgprimary
barman is installed on pgbackup

I want to backup data from pgprimary on pgbackupsame 2 users as Postgress users

on each machine I created
2 Linux sudoist users

```
useradd barman
useradd streaming_barman
```

also created the same two user as Postgress users

```
createuser --superuser --replication -P barman
createuser --superuser --replication -P streaming_barman
```

here are relevant parts on the configuration files

### On pgprimary

### postgressql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
port = 5432 


archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/12/arc/%f'
wal_level = replica

restore_command = 'cp  /var/lib/postgresql/12/arc/%f %p'
recovery_target_time = '2021-03-24 16:18:11.319298+05:30'
recovery_target_inclusive = false
```

---

### pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

#local   replication     all                                     peer
#host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5

# FOR TESTING
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

also did

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5432/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

### ========================
con
On pgbackup

```
sudo cat <<'EOF' >> /etc/barman.d/pgprimary.conf
[pgprimary]
description =  "Example of PostgreSQL Database (Streaming-Only)"
conninfo = host=192.168.1.131 user=barman dbname=training
streaming_conninfo = host=192.168.1.131 user=streaming_barman dbname=training
backup_method = postgres
streaming_archiver = on
slot_name = barman
create_slot = auto
EOF
```

---

### pg_hba.conf

```
cat <<'EOF' >>~/.pgpass
pgprimary:*:*:barman:barman
pgprimary:*:*:streaming_barman:barman
EOF
```

Then I did

```
barman cron
```

Output

```
Starting WAL archiving for server pgprimary
Starting streaming archiver for server pgprimary


barman check pgprimary
```

Then I get this error

```
 [13643] barman.utils WARNING: Failed opening the requested log file. Using standard error instead.
Server pgprimary:
2021-10-30 21:39:15,982 [13643] barman.server ERROR: Check 'WAL archive' failed for server 'pgprimary'
    WAL archive: FAILED (please make sure WAL shipping is setup)
2021-10-30 21:39:37,006 [13643] barman.postgres WARNING: Error retrieving PostgreSQL status: connection to server at "192.168.131" (192.168.0.131), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
2021-10-30 21:39:58,021 [13643] barman.server ERROR: Check 'check timeout' failed for server 'pgprimary'
    check timeout: FAILED (barman check command timed out)
```

Why cannot connect barman to the server ?

UPDATE:

```
psql -h 192.168.1.131 -U barman -d training
Password for user barman: 

psql (12.8 (Ubuntu 12.8-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.
```

I also can connect to server via netstat

Comment: Your servers are listening on `192.168.1.x` yet your `pg_hba.conf` is only allowing connections from `local` and `localhost`. That seems to be a mismatch. Also in `pg_hba.conf` first match wins and that would be the `md5` lines for `host` so you will need to supply a password. What happens if you do `psql -h 192.168.1.131 -U barman -d training`?

Comment: psql -h 192.168.1.131 -U barman -d training
Password for user barman: 
psql (12.8 (Ubuntu 12.8-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

Comment: Add your comment as update to your question so folks don't have to dig through the comments for information. You are not supplying a password in your `Barman` config so I'm guessing this is the problem.